# System.Reactive dll is missing

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll

My project is missing System.Reactive dll (shows yellow explanatory icon).
I am using Visual Studio 2015 (community) with .net 4.5

Can anyone help me with this? Should I have to install any separate SDK?

Comment: Try NuGetting "Rx-Main" (or "Rx-WinForms" or "Rx-WPF", etc).

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to get external dependencies is via a package manager. In .NET/Visual Studio, the packagemanager is called Nuget. Either the project/solution that you are opening does not have Nuget Restore enabled, or they have linked to it directly. Either way, you probably will have the most success if you include the package via Nuget

In Visual Studio 2015 follow these menu items

1. *Right Click* on the Project that has the yellow triangle
2. Click *Manage Nuget packages...*
3. Choose the *Browse* tab
4. Enter 'Rx-Main' in the search text box
5. Click the *Rx-Main* result
6. Click the *Install* button on the right side pane 
   `

Comment: Couldn't resist Lee, sorry. :D

Comment: Rx-Main no longer exists, shouldn't we use [Install-Package System.Reactive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reactive/) instead?

Comment: Rx-main does exist, it just has been deprecated (in the year since this post). Correct the package is System.Reactive, and yes using the package manager console is marginally less a skin crawling experience

Answer (score 1):

You need to search for 'System.Reactive' in Nuget.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to get external dependencies is via a package manager. In .NET/Visual Studio, the packagemanager is called Nuget. Either the project/solution that you are opening does not have Nuget Restore enabled, or they have linked to it directly. Either way, you probably will have the most success if you include the package via Nuget

In Visual Studio 2015 follow these menu items

1. Click View>Other Windows>Package Manager Console
2. In the window that appears or gains focus, ensure the project with the missing DLL is selected in the drop down.
3. Type `install-package rx-main`

You can use the GUI for nuget as Lee described, but this is a much more hardcore and cool way to do it. To be *really cool* you can do `install-package rx-main -project <name of project>` and miss out step 2!